# Coding styles in conditional expression of some programming languages

Tags: coding-style, conditional-statements

It's a bit confusing to me about what is the difference between these condition expressions below:

```
if( 1 == a) { 
   //something
}
```

and

```
if( a == 1 ) {
   //something
}
```

I saw the above one in some scripts I have downloaded and I wonder what's the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former has been coined a [Yoda Condition](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

Using if(constant == variable) instead of if(variable == constant), like if(1 == a). Because it's like saying "if blue is the sky" or "if tall is the man".

Comment: Could you please correct that link to "Yo ***d*** a Condition" instead of Yoga?

Comment: good spot, must have had yoga on the mind.  it would be fine for you to edit an answer like that yourself.

Comment: 1 char is too minor of an edit, because I don't have enough rep to edit without suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The `constant == variable` syntax is often used to avoid mistyping `==` as `=`. It is, of course, often used without understanding also when you have `constant == function_call_retuning_nothing_modifiable`.

Other than that there's no difference, unless you have some weird operator override.

Comment: So you meant that using if( 1 = a ) could be as if( 1 == a) or if (a == 1) ?

Comment: If you mistype `if(1=a)` you error out, if you mistype `if(a=1)` it may go unnoticed, but lead to undesired results.

Answer (score 1):

Many programming languages allow assignments like `a = 1` to be used as expressions, making the following code syntactically valid (given that integers can be used in conditionals, such as in C or many scripting languages):

```
if (a = 1) {
    // something
}
```

This is rarely desired, and can lead to unexpected behavior.  If `1 == a` is used, then this mistake cannot occur because `1 = a` is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure about the trick. Generally, we could say the equal sign is commutative. So, a = b implies b = a. However, when you have == or === this doesn't work in certain cases, for example when on the right side you have a range: 5 === (1..10) vs. (1..10) === 5.